# CakePHP bcrypt not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

each time I call

```
$bph = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
return $bph->hash("test");
```

it gives me a different string. what's wrong?

**Edit:**

also

```
return Security::hash("test", "blowfish);
```

stills give me different strings each time

salt

```
Configure::write('Security.salt', 'VFxyv9RHDvtc4WUOxNTx54V1qikWpy2eZ15iFKlb');
```

Comment: Your salt is probably being regenerated each time, which would produce a different hash. Can you provide your own salt?

Comment: what salt? I the one in `core.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this:

By definition the security hash is

```
Security::hash($string, $type = NULL, $salt = false);
```

Blowfish is more secure like bcrypt.

But use of blowfish is little bit different form other algorithms.

Like md5, sha1 etc.

Each time you pass a string($string) it will returns the same result.

But the blowfish creates each time new results.

When comparing values hashed with bcrypt, the original hash should be provided as the $salt parameter.

**Example:**

For creating use:

```
$string = 'CakePhp';
// Create a hash using bcrypt
Security::setHash('blowfish');
$hash = Security::hash($string); // $hash is your blowfish hashed string
```

For Comparing:

```
$newHash = Security::hash($string, 'blowfish', $hash);
If($hash == $newHash){
   echo "Matching.....";
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: I understand. Does that means I cannot use the Auth component to log in? since the whole problem is that AuthComponent::login() doesntwork

Comment: You should ask a seperate question about that @ChristopherFrancisco (No, it does not mean that). It's by design that blowfish gives a different result for the same input - you're trying to treat it as a simple hash and that's not how it works [see the docs](http://es1.php.net/crypt#refsect1-function.crypt-examples).